# Counting intersecting time intervals in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (CoachID INT, BusyST DATETIME, BusyET DATETIME)
CREATE TABLE #Temp2 (CoachID INT, AvailableST DATETIME, AvailableET DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Temp1 (CoachID, BusyST, BusyET)
SELECT 1,'2016-08-17 09:12:00','2016-08-17 10:11:00'
UNION
SELECT 3,'2016-08-17 09:30:00','2016-08-17 10:00:00'
UNION
SELECT 4,'2016-08-17 12:07:00','2016-08-17 13:10:00'

INSERT INTO #Temp2 (CoachID, AvailableST, AvailableET)
SELECT 1,'2016-08-17 09:07:00','2016-08-17 11:09:00'
UNION
SELECT 2,'2016-08-17 09:11:00','2016-08-17 09:30:00'
UNION
SELECT 3,'2016-08-17 09:24:00','2016-08-17 13:08:00'
UNION
SELECT 1,'2016-08-17 11:34:00','2016-08-17 12:27:00'
UNION
SELECT 4,'2016-08-17 09:34:00','2016-08-17 13:00:00'
UNION
SELECT 5,'2016-08-17 09:10:00','2016-08-17 09:55:00'

--RESULT-SET QUERY GOES HERE

DROP TABLE #Temp1
DROP TABLE #Temp2
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
CoachID CanCoachST                  CanCoachET                  NumOfCoaches
1       2016-08-17 09:12:00.000     2016-08-17 09:24:00.000     2 --(ID2 = 2,5)
1       2016-08-17 09:24:00.000     2016-08-17 09:30:00.000     3 --(ID2 = 2,3,5)
1       2016-08-17 09:30:00.000     2016-08-17 09:34:00.000     1 --(ID2 = 5)
1       2016-08-17 09:34:00.000     2016-08-17 09:55:00.000     2 --(ID2 = 4,5)
1       2016-08-17 09:55:00.000     2016-08-17 10:00:00.000     1 --(ID2 = 4)
1       2016-08-17 10:00:00.000     2016-08-17 10:11:00.000     2 --(ID2 = 3,4)
3       2016-08-17 09:30:00.000     2016-08-17 09:34:00.000     1 --(ID2 = 5)
3       2016-08-17 09:34:00.000     2016-08-17 09:55:00.000     2 --(ID2 = 4,5)
3       2016-08-17 09:55:00.000     2016-08-17 10:00:00.000     1 --(ID2 = 4)
4       2016-08-17 12:07:00.000     2016-08-17 12:27:00.000     2 --(ID2 = 1,3)
4       2016-08-17 12:27:00.000     2016-08-17 13:08:00.000     1 --(ID2 = 3)
4       2016-08-17 13:08:00.000     2016-08-17 13:10:00.000     0 --(No one is available)
```

GOAL:
Consider `#Temp1` as the table of team coaches (ID1) and their meeting times (ST1 = Meeting Start Time and ET1 = Meeting End Time).
Consider `#Temp2` as the table of team coaches (ID2) and their total available times (ST2 = Available Start Time and ET2 = Available End Time).

Now, the goal is to find all possible coaches from `#Temp2` who are available to coach during the meeting time of the coaches from `#Temp1`.

So for example, For the coach ID1 = 1, who is busy between 9:12 and 10:11 (data can span across multiple days, if that info matters), we have 
coach ID2 = 2 and 5 that can coach between 9:12 and 9:24
, coach ID2 = 2,3, and 5 that can coach between 9:24 and 9:30
, coach ID2 = 5 that can coach between 9:30 and 9:34
, coach ID2 = 4 and 5 that can coach between 9:34 and 9:55
, coach ID2 = 4 that can coach between 9:55 and 10:00
, and coach ID2 = 3 and 4 that can coach between 10:00 and 10:11 (note how ID 3, although available in #Temp2 table between 9:24 and 13:08, it can't coach for ID1 = 1 between 9:24 and 10:00 because its also busy between 9:30 and 10:00.

My effort so far: Only dealing with breaking #Temp1's time bracket so far. Still need to figure out A) how to remove that non-busy time window from the output B) add a field/map it to right T1's CoachIDs.

```
;WITH ED
AS (SELECT BusyET, CoachID FROM #Temp1  
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT BusyST, CoachID FROM #Temp1
    )
,Brackets
AS (SELECT MIN(BusyST) AS BusyST
        ,(  SELECT MIN(BusyET)
            FROM ED e
            WHERE e.BusyET > MIN(BusyST)
            ) AS BusyET
    FROM #Temp1 T   
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT B.BusyET
        ,e.BusyET
    FROM Brackets B
    INNER JOIN ED E ON B.BusyET < E.BusyET
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM ED E2
            WHERE E2.BusyET > B.BusyET
                AND E2.BusyET < E.BusyET
            )
    )
SELECT *
FROM Brackets
ORDER BY BusyST;
```

I think I need to join on comparing ST/ET dates between two tables where IDs don't match each other. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually get only the meeting time window and unique count.

Updated with better schema/data-set. Also note, even though CoachID 4 is not "scheduled" to be available, he's still listed as busy for that last few minutes. And there can be scenario where no one else is available to work during that time, in which case, we can return 0 cnt record (or not return it if it's really complicated).

Again, the goal is to find count and combination of all available CoachIDs and their Available time window that can coach for the CoachIDs listed in the busy table.

Updated with more sample description matching sample data.

Comment: Your sample data is confusing. You say only ID2 2,3,5 can fill in for ID1's first half hour but your sample data shows ID2 1 being available in that time... The rest of the sample data compared to expected output is just as confusing...

Comment: I think the #Temp2 is just the working hours/shifts of each coaches.

Comment: @ZLK, Yea, TT1 is for coach's meeting time and TT2 is for coach's possible working time. so when we return ID1 = 1's result set, we should not return that time from TT2 for the ID2 = 1.

Comment: do you have a minimum interval / duration that you would want to schedule someone for? e.g. 30 minutes or 15 minutes?

Comment: @JohnDaCosta, there is no minimum/max/set duration. :(

Comment: @007 i guess if you are running it on a daily basis and using only integer of 4 bytes, scheduling by the second you will get only 4 bytes * 4 columns * 86400 seconds for each coach per day on the fact table in my design below --> (1.32MB) per day per coach in the system on the fact table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query in this answer was inspired by the [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/) by Itzik Ben-Gan.

---

At first I didn't understand the full complexity of the requirements and assumed that intervals in `Table1` and `Table2` don't overlap. I assumed that the same coach can't be busy and available at the same time.

It turns out that my assumption was wrong, so the first variant of the query that I'm leaving below has to be extended with preliminary step that subtracts all intervals stored in `Table1` from intervals stored in `Table2`.

It uses the similar idea. Each start of the "available" interval is marked with +1 `EventType` and end of the "available" interval is marked with -1 `EventType`. For "busy" intervals the marks are reversed. "Busy" interval starts with -1 and ends with +1. This is done in `C1_Subtract`.

Then running total tells us where the "truly" available intervals are (`C2_Subtract`). Finally, `CTE_Available` leaves only "truly" available intervals.

**Sample data**

I added few rows to illustrate what happens if no coaches are available. I also added `CoachID=9`, which is not in the initial results of the first variant of the query.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (CoachID INT, BusyST DATETIME, BusyET DATETIME);
CREATE TABLE #Temp2 (CoachID INT, AvailableST DATETIME, AvailableET DATETIME);
-- Start time is inclusive
-- End time is exclusive

INSERT INTO #Temp1 (CoachID, BusyST, BusyET) VALUES
(1, '2016-08-17 09:12:00','2016-08-17 10:11:00'),
(3, '2016-08-17 09:30:00','2016-08-17 10:00:00'),
(4, '2016-08-17 12:07:00','2016-08-17 13:10:00'),

(6, '2016-08-17 15:00:00','2016-08-17 16:00:00'),
(9, '2016-08-17 15:00:00','2016-08-17 16:00:00');

INSERT INTO #Temp2 (CoachID, AvailableST, AvailableET) VALUES
(1,'2016-08-17 09:07:00','2016-08-17 11:09:00'),
(2,'2016-08-17 09:11:00','2016-08-17 09:30:00'),
(3,'2016-08-17 09:24:00','2016-08-17 13:08:00'),
(1,'2016-08-17 11:34:00','2016-08-17 12:27:00'),
(4,'2016-08-17 09:34:00','2016-08-17 13:00:00'),
(5,'2016-08-17 09:10:00','2016-08-17 09:55:00'),

(7,'2016-08-17 15:10:00','2016-08-17 15:20:00'),
(8,'2016-08-17 15:15:00','2016-08-17 15:25:00'),
(7,'2016-08-17 15:40:00','2016-08-17 15:55:00'),
(9,'2016-08-17 15:05:00','2016-08-17 15:07:00'),
(9,'2016-08-17 15:40:00','2016-08-17 16:55:00');
```

**Intermediate results of `CTE_Available`**

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| CoachID |       AvailableST       |       AvailableET       |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:07:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:12:00.000 |
|       1 | 2016-08-17 10:11:00.000 | 2016-08-17 11:09:00.000 |
|       1 | 2016-08-17 11:34:00.000 | 2016-08-17 12:27:00.000 |
|       2 | 2016-08-17 09:11:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:30:00.000 |
|       3 | 2016-08-17 09:24:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:30:00.000 |
|       3 | 2016-08-17 10:00:00.000 | 2016-08-17 13:08:00.000 |
|       4 | 2016-08-17 09:34:00.000 | 2016-08-17 12:07:00.000 |
|       5 | 2016-08-17 09:10:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:55:00.000 |
|       7 | 2016-08-17 15:10:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:20:00.000 |
|       7 | 2016-08-17 15:40:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:55:00.000 |
|       8 | 2016-08-17 15:15:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:25:00.000 |
|       9 | 2016-08-17 16:00:00.000 | 2016-08-17 16:55:00.000 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Now we can use these intermediate results of `CTE_Available` instead of `#Temp2` in the first variant of the query. See detailed explanations below the first variant of the query.

**Full query**

```
WITH
C1_Subtract
AS
(
    SELECT
        CoachID
        ,AvailableST AS ts
        ,+1 AS EventType
    FROM #Temp2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CoachID
        ,AvailableET AS ts
        ,-1 AS EventType
    FROM #Temp2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CoachID
        ,BusyST AS ts
        ,-1 AS EventType
    FROM #Temp1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CoachID
        ,BusyET AS ts
        ,+1 AS EventType
    FROM #Temp1
)
,C2_Subtract AS
(
    SELECT
        C1_Subtract.*
        ,SUM(EventType)
            OVER (
            PARTITION BY CoachID
            ORDER BY ts, EventType DESC
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        AS cnt
        ,LEAD(ts) 
            OVER (
            PARTITION BY CoachID
            ORDER BY ts, EventType DESC)
        AS NextTS
    FROM C1_Subtract
)
,CTE_Available
AS
(
    SELECT
        C2_Subtract.CoachID
        ,C2_Subtract.ts AS AvailableST
        ,C2_Subtract.NextTS AS AvailableET
    FROM C2_Subtract
    WHERE cnt > 0
)
,CTE_Intervals
AS
(
    SELECT
        TBusy.CoachID AS BusyCoachID
        ,TBusy.BusyST
        ,TBusy.BusyET
        ,CA.CoachID AS AvailableCoachID
        ,CA.AvailableST
        ,CA.AvailableET
        -- max of start time
        ,CASE WHEN CA.AvailableST < TBusy.BusyST
        THEN TBusy.BusyST
        ELSE CA.AvailableST 
        END AS ST
        -- min of end time
        ,CASE WHEN CA.AvailableET > TBusy.BusyET
        THEN TBusy.BusyET
        ELSE CA.AvailableET
        END AS ET
    FROM
        #Temp1 AS TBusy
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT
                TAvailable.*
            FROM
                CTE_Available AS TAvailable
            WHERE
                -- the same coach can't be available and busy
                TAvailable.CoachID <> TBusy.CoachID
                -- intervals intersect
                AND TAvailable.AvailableST < TBusy.BusyET
                AND TAvailable.AvailableET > TBusy.BusyST
        ) AS CA
)
,C1 AS
(
    SELECT
        BusyCoachID
        ,AvailableCoachID
        ,ST AS ts
        ,+1 AS EventType
    FROM CTE_Intervals

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        BusyCoachID
        ,AvailableCoachID
        ,ET AS ts
        ,-1 AS EventType
    FROM CTE_Intervals

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CoachID AS BusyCoachID
        ,CoachID AS AvailableCoachID
        ,BusyST AS ts
        ,+1 AS EventType
    FROM #Temp1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CoachID AS BusyCoachID
        ,CoachID AS AvailableCoachID
        ,BusyET AS ts
        ,-1 AS EventType
    FROM #Temp1
)
,C2 AS
(
    SELECT
        C1.*
        ,SUM(EventType)
            OVER (
            PARTITION BY BusyCoachID
            ORDER BY ts, EventType DESC, AvailableCoachID
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        - 1 AS cnt
        ,LEAD(ts) 
            OVER (
            PARTITION BY BusyCoachID 
            ORDER BY ts, EventType DESC, AvailableCoachID) 
        AS NextTS
    FROM C1
)
SELECT
    BusyCoachID AS CoachID
    ,ts AS CanCoachST
    ,NextTS AS CanCoachET
    ,cnt AS NumOfCoaches
FROM C2
WHERE ts <> NextTS
ORDER BY BusyCoachID, CanCoachST
;
```

**Final result**

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| CoachID |       CanCoachST        |       CanCoachET        | NumOfCoaches |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:12:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:24:00.000 |            2 |
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:24:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:30:00.000 |            3 |
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:30:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:34:00.000 |            1 |
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:34:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:55:00.000 |            2 |
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:55:00.000 | 2016-08-17 10:00:00.000 |            1 |
|       1 | 2016-08-17 10:00:00.000 | 2016-08-17 10:11:00.000 |            2 |
|       3 | 2016-08-17 09:30:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:34:00.000 |            1 |
|       3 | 2016-08-17 09:34:00.000 | 2016-08-17 09:55:00.000 |            2 |
|       3 | 2016-08-17 09:55:00.000 | 2016-08-17 10:00:00.000 |            1 |
|       4 | 2016-08-17 12:07:00.000 | 2016-08-17 12:27:00.000 |            2 |
|       4 | 2016-08-17 12:27:00.000 | 2016-08-17 13:08:00.000 |            1 |
|       4 | 2016-08-17 13:08:00.000 | 2016-08-17 13:10:00.000 |            0 |
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:00:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:10:00.000 |            0 |
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:10:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:15:00.000 |            1 |
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:15:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:20:00.000 |            2 |
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:20:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:25:00.000 |            1 |
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:25:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:40:00.000 |            0 |
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:40:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:55:00.000 |            1 |
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:55:00.000 | 2016-08-17 16:00:00.000 |            0 |
|       9 | 2016-08-17 15:00:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:10:00.000 |            0 |
|       9 | 2016-08-17 15:10:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:15:00.000 |            1 |
|       9 | 2016-08-17 15:15:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:20:00.000 |            2 |
|       9 | 2016-08-17 15:20:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:25:00.000 |            1 |
|       9 | 2016-08-17 15:25:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:40:00.000 |            0 |
|       9 | 2016-08-17 15:40:00.000 | 2016-08-17 15:55:00.000 |            1 |
|       9 | 2016-08-17 15:55:00.000 | 2016-08-17 16:00:00.000 |            0 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

I'd recommend to create the following indexes to avoid some Sorts in the execution plan.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CoachID_BusyST] ON #Temp1
(
    CoachID ASC,
    BusyST ASC
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CoachID_BusyET] ON #Temp1
(
    CoachID ASC,
    BusyET ASC
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CoachID_AvailableST] ON #Temp2
(
    CoachID ASC,
    AvailableST ASC
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CoachID_AvailableET] ON #Temp2
(
    CoachID ASC,
    AvailableET ASC
);
```

On real data, though, the bottleneck may be somewhere else, which may depend on the data distribution. The query is rather complicated and tuning it without real data would be too much guesswork.

---

### **First variant of the query**

Run the query step-by-step, CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to undestand how it works.

`CTE_Intervals` gives us a list of available intervals that intersect with busy intervals.
`C1` puts both start and end times in the same column with the corresponding `EventType`. This will help us track when an interval starts or ends.
A running total of `EventType` gives the count of available coaches. `C1` unions busy coaches into the mix to properly count cases when no coach is available.

```
WITH
CTE_Intervals
AS
(
    SELECT
        TBusy.CoachID AS BusyCoachID
        ,TBusy.BusyST
        ,TBusy.BusyET
        ,CA.CoachID AS AvailableCoachID
        ,CA.AvailableST
        ,CA.AvailableET
        -- max of start time
        ,CASE WHEN CA.AvailableST < TBusy.BusyST
        THEN TBusy.BusyST
        ELSE CA.AvailableST 
        END AS ST
        -- min of end time
        ,CASE WHEN CA.AvailableET > TBusy.BusyET
        THEN TBusy.BusyET
        ELSE CA.AvailableET
        END AS ET
    FROM
        #Temp1 AS TBusy
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT
                TAvailable.*
            FROM
                #Temp2 AS TAvailable
            WHERE
                -- the same coach can't be available and busy
                TAvailable.CoachID <> TBusy.CoachID
                -- intervals intersect
                AND TAvailable.AvailableST < TBusy.BusyET
                AND TAvailable.AvailableET > TBusy.BusyST
        ) AS CA
)
,C1 AS
(
    SELECT
        BusyCoachID
        ,AvailableCoachID
        ,ST AS ts
        ,+1 AS EventType
    FROM CTE_Intervals

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        BusyCoachID
        ,AvailableCoachID
        ,ET AS ts
        ,-1 AS EventType
    FROM CTE_Intervals

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CoachID AS BusyCoachID
        ,CoachID AS AvailableCoachID
        ,BusyST AS ts
        ,+1 AS EventType
    FROM #Temp1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CoachID AS BusyCoachID
        ,CoachID AS AvailableCoachID
        ,BusyET AS ts
        ,-1 AS EventType
    FROM #Temp1
)
,C2 AS
(
    SELECT
        C1.*
        ,SUM(EventType)
            OVER (
            PARTITION BY BusyCoachID
            ORDER BY ts, EventType DESC, AvailableCoachID
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        - 1 AS cnt
        ,LEAD(ts) 
            OVER (
            PARTITION BY BusyCoachID 
            ORDER BY ts, EventType DESC, AvailableCoachID) 
        AS NextTS
    FROM C1
)
SELECT
    BusyCoachID AS CoachID
    ,ts AS CanCoachST
    ,NextTS AS CanCoachET
    ,cnt AS NumOfCoaches
FROM C2
WHERE ts <> NextTS
ORDER BY BusyCoachID, CanCoachST
;

DROP TABLE #Temp1;
DROP TABLE #Temp2;
```

**Result**

I've added comments for each line with IDs of available coaches that were counted.

Now I understand why my initial result was not the same as your expected result.

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| CoachID |       CanCoachST    |       CanCoachET    | NumOfCoaches |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:12:00 | 2016-08-17 09:24:00 |            2 |  2,5
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:24:00 | 2016-08-17 09:30:00 |            3 |  2,3,5
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:30:00 | 2016-08-17 09:34:00 |            2 |  3,5
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:34:00 | 2016-08-17 09:55:00 |            3 |  3,4,5
|       1 | 2016-08-17 09:55:00 | 2016-08-17 10:11:00 |            2 |  3,4
|       3 | 2016-08-17 09:30:00 | 2016-08-17 09:34:00 |            2 |  1,5
|       3 | 2016-08-17 09:34:00 | 2016-08-17 09:55:00 |            3 |  1,4,5
|       3 | 2016-08-17 09:55:00 | 2016-08-17 10:00:00 |            2 |  1,4
|       4 | 2016-08-17 12:07:00 | 2016-08-17 12:27:00 |            2 |  3,1
|       4 | 2016-08-17 12:27:00 | 2016-08-17 13:08:00 |            1 |  3
|       4 | 2016-08-17 13:08:00 | 2016-08-17 13:10:00 |            0 |  none
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:00:00 | 2016-08-17 15:10:00 |            0 |  none
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:10:00 | 2016-08-17 15:15:00 |            1 |  7
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:15:00 | 2016-08-17 15:20:00 |            2 |  7,8
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:20:00 | 2016-08-17 15:25:00 |            1 |  8
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:25:00 | 2016-08-17 15:40:00 |            0 |  none
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:40:00 | 2016-08-17 15:55:00 |            1 |  7
|       6 | 2016-08-17 15:55:00 | 2016-08-17 16:00:00 |            0 |  none
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Vlad, this is almost what I want. Just one thing, #Temp2.CoachID 3 is available between 09:24 and 13:08. But because s/he's busy (#Temp1.CoachID = 3) between 9:30 and 10:00, it should not be part of the output for CoachID 1 between 9:30 and 9:34 AND 9:34 and 9:55 AND 9:55 and 10:00. It IS however available between 9:24 and 9:30 AND 10:00 and 10:00. Similar for other IDs. Otherwise, this is pretty awesome. Also, thanks for Itzik's blog post.

Comment: @007, hmm. So, you have conflicting data in two tables. Table2 says that a coach is available, but Table1 contradicts it and says that it is busy. Besides, based on your comment, there is an implicit rule that "busy" table has higher priority. You should try to rectify this design. It is highly confusing. Try to convert your data into simpler arrangement when this kind of conflict doesn't exist. My answer assumed that such conflicts don't exist. It is an important bit of information and it should have been included in the question.

Comment: @007, Do you really want to clean up and resolve these conflicts between busy and available times of the same coaches "on the fly" within the query? Essentially you need to subtract intervals stored in Table1 from intervals stored in Table2. It should be possible, but doing it every time on the fly may be quite inefficient.

Comment: @007, Frankly speaking, the query that subtracts "busy" intervals from "available" intervals is a good question by itself. Anyway, I extended the query in the answer to perform this preliminary step. Now the final result is the same as your expected result in the question.

Comment: @VladmirBaranov, consider #T2 as a working hours for each coach table and #T1 as, no matter what the working hours are, s/he is busy during these hours (whether scheduled to coach or not). Now, we need to find, who can cover the coaches that are busy during those times?. Your sln works as expected and Thank you so much for updating it. As for inefficiency, I'll have to take a look at it as this query will be used against huge dataset and quite often. Thank you again!!

Comment: @007 you are welcome and thank you for the bounty. You've got several answers that return correct results, it would be interesting to see their relative performance on real data. I understand, that it may be tricky to do the proper comparison, because different methods may require different indexes to perform well, but still... I've added my recommendations for indexes to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, what you're looking for is something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID1, ST1, DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, ST1) ET1
    FROM #Temp1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.ID1, C.ET1, DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, C.ET1)
    FROM CTE C
    JOIN #Temp1 T ON T.ID1 = C.ID1
    WHERE T.ET1 >= DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, C.ET1))
SELECT *
FROM CTE C
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) ID2Cnt
    FROM #Temp2 T
    WHERE ST2 <= C.ST1
    AND ET2 >= C.ET1
    AND ID2 <> C.ID1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM CTE
        WHERE ID1 = T.ID2
        AND ST1 <= C.ST1
        AND ET1 >= C.ET1)) T
ORDER BY ID1, ST1;
```

The CTE will split your #Temp1 coaches up into half hour slots, and then I'm assuming you want to find all the people in #Temp2 who aren't the same ID and have a shift that starts earlier or at the same time and ends after or at the same time... **NOTE:** I'm assuming blocks can only be half an hour here.

EDIT: Never mind... I just realised you also want to discount the busy people in #Temp1 from the result set so I added a not exists clause in the apply...

Comment: Will check this soon but the thing is that the blocks can be any number of minutes..:(

Comment: @007 How would you decide what sort of blocks there are going to be if it's not half hour blocks? Would they always end/start on a half hour point? (e.g. if someone is busy 9:15 to 9:40, would you be looking for one 15 minute and one 10 minute block? or just one 25 minute block?)

Comment: Updated the OP with better data set. Basically, we need to look at the busy table (#Temp2), and for all CoachIDs and their busy time, find combination of time windows of the coaches who are not busy (not in #Temp1) AND available to work (in #Temp2) and the counts. And yea, the time would break into each time window combination as long as an additional coach can be counted and vice-versa. does this help?

Answer (score 1):

This query will do the calculations:

```
SELECT TT1.ID1
 , case when TT2.ST2 < TT1.ST1 THEN TT1.ST1 ELSE TT2.ST2 END
 , case when TT2.ET2 > TT1.ET1 THEN TT1.ET1 ELSE TT2.ET2 END
 , COUNT(distinct TT2.id2) 
FROM #Temp1 TT1 INNER JOIN #Temp2 TT2
ON TT1.ET1 > TT2.ST2 AND TT1.ST1 < TT2.ET2 AND TT1.ID1 <> TT2.ID2
GROUP BY TT1.ID1
 , case when TT2.ST2 < TT1.ST1 THEN TT1.ST1 ELSE TT2.ST2 END
 , case when TT2.ET2 > TT1.ET1 THEN TT1.ET1 ELSE TT2.ET2 END
```

However, the result will include the slots where coaches cal fill in for the full time slot, e.g for the Coach 1 there will be three slots: from 9:00 to 9:30 with substitute coach #2, from 9:30 to 10:00 substitute coach #4 and the timeslot from 9:00 to 10:00 with substitute coaches #3 and #4. Here is the whole result:

```
ID1                                                         
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
1           2016-08-17 09:00:00.000 2016-08-17 09:30:00.000 1
1           2016-08-17 09:00:00.000 2016-08-17 10:00:00.000 2
1           2016-08-17 09:30:00.000 2016-08-17 10:00:00.000 1
3           2016-08-17 09:30:00.000 2016-08-17 10:00:00.000 3
4           2016-08-17 12:00:00.000 2016-08-17 12:30:00.000 1
4           2016-08-17 12:00:00.000 2016-08-17 13:00:00.000 1
```

Comment: Thanks @cha for your input. The only thing is, that partial/complete count can cause confusion so we need to get unique partial counts.

Answer (score 1):

This is your expected result that is taking into consideration of the Busy Coaches that overlap the Available Coaches.

```
| CoachID | CanCoachST       | CanCoachET       | NumOfCoaches | CanCoach |
|---------|------------------|------------------|--------------|----------|
| 1       | 2016-08-17 09:12 | 2016-08-17 09:24 | 2            | 2, 5     |
| 1       | 2016-08-17 09:24 | 2016-08-17 09:30 | 3            | 2, 3, 5  |
| 1       | 2016-08-17 09:30 | 2016-08-17 09:34 | 1            | 5        |
| 1       | 2016-08-17 09:34 | 2016-08-17 09:55 | 2            | 4, 5     |
| 1       | 2016-08-17 09:55 | 2016-08-17 10:00 | 1            | 4        |
| 1       | 2016-08-17 10:00 | 2016-08-17 10:11 | 2            | 3, 4     |
| 3       | 2016-08-17 09:30 | 2016-08-17 09:34 | 1            | 5        |
| 3       | 2016-08-17 09:34 | 2016-08-17 09:55 | 2            | 4, 5     |
| 3       | 2016-08-17 09:55 | 2016-08-17 10:00 | 1            | 4        |
| 4       | 2016-08-17 12:07 | 2016-08-17 12:27 | 2            | 1, 3     |
| 4       | 2016-08-17 12:27 | 2016-08-17 13:08 | 1            | 3        |
| 4       | 2016-08-17 13:08 | 2016-08-17 13:10 | 0            | NULL     |
```

`#Temp1` as Busy Coaches:

```
| CoachID | BusyST           | BusyET           |
|---------|------------------|------------------|
| 1       | 2016-08-17 09:12 | 2016-08-17 10:11 |
| 3       | 2016-08-17 09:30 | 2016-08-17 10:00 |
| 4       | 2016-08-17 12:07 | 2016-08-17 13:10 |
```

`#Temp2` as Available Coaches:

```
| CoachID | AvailableST      | AvailableET      |
|---------|------------------|------------------|
| 1       | 2016-08-17 09:07 | 2016-08-17 11:09 |
| 1       | 2016-08-17 11:34 | 2016-08-17 12:27 |
| 2       | 2016-08-17 09:11 | 2016-08-17 09:30 |
| 3       | 2016-08-17 09:24 | 2016-08-17 13:08 |
| 4       | 2016-08-17 09:34 | 2016-08-17 13:00 |
| 5       | 2016-08-17 09:10 | 2016-08-17 09:55 |
```

The script below is a bit long.

```
;
with
st 
(
    CoachID,
    CanCoachST
)
as
(
    select 
        bound.CoachID,
        s.BusyST 
    from 
        #Temp1 as s 
    cross apply
    (
        select
            b.CoachID,
            b.BusyST,
            b.BusyET
        from
            #Temp1 as b
        where 1 = 1
        and s.BusyST between b.BusyST and b.BusyET
    )
    as bound

    union all

    select 
        bound.CoachID,
        s.BusyET 
    from 
        #Temp1 as s 
    cross apply
    (
        select
            b.CoachID,
            b.BusyST,
            b.BusyET
        from
            #Temp1 as b
        where 1 = 1
        and s.BusyET between b.BusyST and b.BusyET
        and s.CoachID != b.CoachID
    )
    as bound

    union all

    select 
        bound.CoachID,
        s.AvailableST 
    from 
        #Temp2 as s 
    cross apply
    (
        select
            b.CoachID,
            b.BusyST,
            b.BusyET
        from
            #Temp1 as b
        where 1 = 1
        and s.AvailableST between b.BusyST and b.BusyET
    )
    as bound

    union all

    select 
        bound.CoachID,
        s.AvailableET 
    from 
        #Temp2 as s 
    cross apply
    (
        select
            b.CoachID,
            b.BusyST,
            b.BusyET
        from
            #Temp1 as b
        where 1 = 1
        and s.AvailableET between b.BusyST and b.BusyET
        and s.CoachID != b.CoachID
    )
    as bound
),
d as
(
    select distinct
        CoachID,
        CanCoachST
    from
        st
),
r as
(
    select
        row_number() over (order by CoachID, CanCoachST) as RowID,
        CoachID,
        CanCoachST
    from
        d
),
rng as
(
    select
        r1.RowID,
        r1.CoachID,
        r1.CanCoachST,
        case when r1.CoachID = r2.CoachID 
            then r2.CanCoachST else t.BusyET end as CanCoachET
    from
        r as r1
    left join
        r as r2
    on
        r1.RowID = r2.RowID - 1
    left join
        #Temp1 as t
    on
        t.CoachID = r1.CoachID
),
c as
(
    select
        rng.RowID,
        rng.CoachID,
        rng.CanCoachST,
        rng.CanCoachET,
        t2.CoachID as CanCoachID
    from
        rng
    cross join
        #Temp1 as t1
    cross join
        #Temp2 as t2
    where 1 = 1
    and t2.CoachID != rng.CoachID
    and t2.AvailableST <= rng.CanCoachST
    and t2.AvailableET >= rng.CanCoachET
),
b as
(
    select
        rng.RowID,
        rng.CoachID,
        rng.CanCoachST,
        rng.CanCoachET,
        t1.CoachID as BusyCoachID
    from
        rng
    cross join
        #Temp1 as t1
    where 1 = 1
    and t1.CoachID != rng.CoachID
    and t1.BusyST <= rng.CanCoachST
    and t1.BusyET >= rng.CanCoachET
),
e as
(
    select
        c.RowID,
        c.CoachID,
        c.CanCoachST,
        c.CanCoachET,
        c.CanCoachID
    from
        c

    except

    select
        b.RowID,
        b.CoachID,
        b.CanCoachST,
        b.CanCoachET,
        b.BusyCoachID
    from
        b
),
f as
(
    select
        rng.RowID,
        rng.CoachID,
        rng.CanCoachST,
        rng.CanCoachET,
        e.CanCoachID
    from
        rng
    left join   
        e
    on
        e.RowID = rng.RowID
)
select
    f.CoachID,
    f.CanCoachST,
    f.CanCoachET,
    count(f.CanCoachID) as NumOfCoaches,
    stuff
    (
        (
            select ', ' + cast(f1.CanCoachID as varchar(5))
                from f as f1 where f1.RowID = f.RowID
                for xml path('')
        ), 
        1, 2, ''
    )
    as CanCoach
from
    f
group by
    f.RowID,
    f.CoachID,
    f.CanCoachST,
    f.CanCoachET
order by
    1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for your input. But similar to Vlad, I see CoachID 3 is showing as available to cover for CoachID 1 between 9:30 and 10:00, but it shouldn't (please refer to my comment to Vlad's post). Otherwise, pretty close. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the concept of an interval / timeslot table.
Another way of explaining it is consider a "Time Dimension Table"

Define all your times, and then record your facts with references to the time intervals at the granularity you care about. Because you had times ending in 7 and 11 minutes I chose 1 minute intervals, though I recommend 15-30 minute intervals.

By doing this it makes it easy to join / compare the tables.

Consider design / implementation below:

-- dimension table

```
-- drop table #intervals
create table #intervals(intervalId  int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered,intervalStartTime datetime unique)
declare @s datetime, @e datetime, @i int 
set @s = '2016-08-16'
set @e = '2016-08-18'
set @i = 1
while (@s <= @e )
begin 
 insert into #intervals(intervalStartTime) values(@s)
 set @s = dateadd(minute, @i, @s)
end
```

-- fact table:

```
-- drop table #Fact
```

create table #Fact(intervalId int, coachid int, isBusy  int default(0) , isAvailable int default(0))

-- record every coach's times

```
   insert into #Fact(coachid,intervalId)
select distinct c.coachid, i.intervalId  
from 
(
select distinct coachid from #temp1
union
select distinct coachid from #temp2
) c cross join #intervals i

-- record free / busy info
update f set isbusy = 1 
from #intervals i inner join #fact f on i.intervalId  = f.intervalId  
inner join #temp1 t on f.coachid = t.coachid and i.intervalStartTime  between t.BusyST and t.BusyET

    -- record free / busy info
update f set isAvailable = 1 
from #intervals i inner join #fact f on i.intervalId  = f.intervalId  
inner join #temp2 t on f.coachid = t.coachid and i.intervalStartTime  between t.AvailableST and t.AvailableET
```

-- construct your query to find common times,etc

```
select * from #intervals i inner join #Fact f on i.intervalId = f.intervalId
```

-- example result showing # of coaches available vs free

select i.intervalId, i.intervalStartTime, sum(isBusy) as coachesBusy, sum(isAvailable) as coachesAvailable
from #intervals i inner join #Fact f on i.intervalId = f.intervalId
group by i.intervalId, i.intervalStartTime
having sum(isBusy) < sum(isAvailable)

[image]

you can then look for common or unique interval ids however you need.

let me know if you require additional clarification.

Comment: i would recommend using an interval of 15 minutes  or 30 minutes, I don't foresee any kind of coaching that could take less than 15 minutes at a time. based on the data in your example I chose 1 minute granularity, but i think that is way too detailed, unless you have a special need / concern

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a little numbers table ... you don't need something for dates, just numbers.  What I am building here is smaller than what you would use in a real scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers (Num INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED);

WITH E1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))     AS t(N))
,E2 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM E1 AS a, E1 AS b)
,E4 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM E2 AS a, E2 AS b)
,cteTally AS (SELECT N = 0 UNION ALL
                SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM     E4)
INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers (Num)
SELECT N FROM cteTally;
```

Pleae note the @startDate below ... it is artificially close to the dates you're dealing with and in a real prod scenario you would have that date be earlier to go along with your larger Numbers table.

Here is the solution to your problem and it will work with older SQL Server versions (as well as the 2012 you have tagged):

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '20160817';
WITH cteBusy AS
(
SELECT  num.Num
    ,   busy.CoachID
FROM #Temp1 AS busy
JOIN dbo.Numbers AS num
    ON num.Num >= DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startDate, busy.BusyST)
    AND num.Num < DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startDate, busy.BusyET)
)
, cteAvailable AS
(
SELECT  num.Num
    ,   avail.CoachID
FROM #Temp2 AS avail
JOIN dbo.Numbers AS num
    ON num.Num >= DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startDate, avail.AvailableST)
    AND num.Num < DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startDate, avail.AvailableET)
LEFT JOIN cteBusy AS b
    ON b.Num = num.Num
    AND b.CoachID = avail.CoachID
WHERE b.Num IS NULL 
)
,   cteGrouping AS
(
SELECT  b.Num
    ,   b.CoachID
    ,   NumOfCoaches = COUNT(a.CoachID)
FROM cteBusy AS b
LEFT JOIN cteAvailable AS a
    ON a.Num = b.Num
GROUP BY b.Num, b.CoachID
)
,   cteFinal AS
(
SELECT  cte.Num
    ,   cte.CoachID
    ,   cte.NumOfCoaches
    ,   block = cte.Num - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cte.CoachID, cte.NumOfCoaches ORDER BY cte.Num)
FROM cteGrouping AS cte
)
SELECT  cte.CoachID
,   CanCoachST = DATEADD(MINUTE, MIN(cte.Num), @startDate)
,   CanCoachET = DATEADD(MINUTE, MAX(cte.Num) + 1, @startDate)
,   cte.NumOfCoaches
FROM cteFinal AS cte
GROUP BY cte.CoachId, cte.NumOfCoaches, cte.block
ORDER BY cte.CoachID, CanCoachST;
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Looks like a tally table type of approach..interesting! Thanks for this input @btberry. Cheers

Comment: It does exactly what you required with much higher performance that what you selected as the correct answer.  Your selection criteria is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following query will work, however I can make no promises on performance.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (CoachID INT, BusyST DATETIME, BusyET DATETIME)
CREATE TABLE #Temp2 (CoachID INT, AvailableST DATETIME, AvailableET DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Temp1 (CoachID, BusyST, BusyET)
SELECT 1,'2016-08-17 09:12:00','2016-08-17 10:11:00'
UNION
SELECT 3,'2016-08-17 09:30:00','2016-08-17 10:00:00'
UNION
SELECT 4,'2016-08-17 12:07:00','2016-08-17 13:10:00'

INSERT INTO #Temp2 (CoachID, AvailableST, AvailableET)
SELECT 1,'2016-08-17 09:07:00','2016-08-17 11:09:00'
UNION
SELECT 2,'2016-08-17 09:11:00','2016-08-17 09:30:00'
UNION
SELECT 3,'2016-08-17 09:24:00','2016-08-17 13:08:00'
UNION
SELECT 1,'2016-08-17 11:34:00','2016-08-17 12:27:00'
UNION
SELECT 4,'2016-08-17 09:34:00','2016-08-17 13:00:00'
UNION
SELECT 5,'2016-08-17 09:10:00','2016-08-17 09:55:00'


;WITH WorkScheduleWithID    -- Select work schedule (#Temp2 – available times) and generate ID for each schedule entry. 
AS
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [CoachID]) AS [ID]
            ,[WS].[CoachID]
            ,[WS].[AvailableST] AS [Start]
            ,[WS].[AvailableET] As [End]
    FROM    #Temp2 [WS]
), SchedulesIntersect -- Determine where work schedule and meeting schedule (busy times) intersect.
AS
(
    SELECT   [ID]
            ,[CoachID]
            ,[Start]
            ,[End]
            ,[IntersectTime]
            ,SUM([Availability]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [IntersectTime]) AS GroupID
    FROM    (
                SELECT       [WS].[ID]
                            ,[WS].[CoachID]
                            ,[WS].[Start]
                            ,[WS].[End]
                            ,[MS1].[BusyST] AS [IntersectTime]
                            ,0 AS [Availability]
                FROM        WorkScheduleWithID [WS]
                INNER JOIN  #Temp1 [MS1] ON ([MS1].[CoachID] = [WS].[CoachID]) 
                                                        AND
                                                     ( ([MS1].[BusyST] > [WS].[Start]) AND ([MS1].[BusyST] < [WS].[End]) ) -- Meeting start contained with in work schedule
                UNION ALL
                SELECT       [WS].[ID]
                            ,[WS].[CoachID]
                            ,[WS].[Start]
                            ,[WS].[End]
                            ,[MS2].[BusyET] AS [IntersectTime]
                            ,1 AS [Availability]
                FROM        WorkScheduleWithID [WS]
                INNER JOIN  #Temp1 [MS2] ON ([MS2].[CoachID] = [WS].[CoachID]) 
                                                        AND
                                                     ( ([MS2].BusyET > [WS].[Start]) AND ([MS2].BusyET < [WS].[End]) )  -- Meeting end contained with in work schedule
            ) Intersects
),ActualAvailability -- Determine actual availability of each coach based on work schedule and busy time.
AS
(
    SELECT   [ID]
            ,[CoachID]
            ,(
                CASE
                    WHEN [GroupID] = 0 THEN [Start]
                    ELSE MIN([IntersectTime]) 
                END
             ) AS [Start]
            ,(
                CASE
                    WHEN ( ([GroupID] > 0) AND (MIN([IntersectTime]) = MAX([IntersectTime])) ) THEN [End]
                    ELSE MAX([IntersectTime]) 
                END
             ) AS [End]
    FROM    SchedulesIntersect
    GROUP BY [ID], [CoachID], [Start], [End], [GroupID]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  [ID]
            ,[CoachID]
            ,[Start]
            ,[End]
    FROM    WorkScheduleWithID WS
    WHERE   WS.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM SchedulesIntersect)
),TimeIntervals -- Determine time intervals for which each coach’s availability will be checked against.
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM    (
                SELECT       MS.CoachID
                            ,MS.BusyST
                            ,MS.BusyET
                            ,(
                                CASE
                                    WHEN AC.Start < MS.BusyST THEN  MS.BusyST 
                                    ELSE AC.Start
                                END
                             )  AS [TS]
                FROM        #Temp1 MS
                LEFT OUTER JOIN ActualAvailability AC ON (AC.CoachID <> MS.CoachID) 
                            AND 
                            (
                                ( (MS.[BusyST] <= AC.[Start]) AND (MS.[BusyET] >= AC.[End]) ) OR                                -- Meeting covers entire work schedule 
                                ( (MS.[BusyST] > AC.[Start]) AND (MS.[BusyET] < AC.[End]) ) OR                              -- Meeting is contained with in work schedule
                                ( (MS.[BusyST] < AC.[Start]) AND (MS.[BusyET] > AC.[Start])  AND ([MS].[BusyET] < AC.[End]) ) OR   -- Meeting ends within work schedule (partial overlap)
                                ( (MS.[BusyST] > AC.[Start]) AND (MS.[BusyST] < AC.[End])  AND ([MS].[BusyET] > AC.[End]) ) -- Meeting starts within work schedule (partial overlap)
                            ) 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT       MS.CoachID
                            ,MS.BusyST
                            ,MS.BusyET
                            ,(
                                CASE
                                    WHEN AC.[End] > MS.BusyET THEN  MS.BusyET 
                                    ELSE AC.[End]
                                END
                             )  AS [TS]
                FROM        #Temp1 MS
                LEFT OUTER JOIN ActualAvailability AC ON (AC.CoachID <> MS.CoachID) 
                            AND 
                            (
                                ( (MS.[BusyST] <= AC.[Start]) AND (MS.[BusyET] >= AC.[End]) ) OR                                -- Meeting covers entire work schedule 
                                ( (MS.[BusyST] > AC.[Start]) AND (MS.[BusyET] < AC.[End]) ) OR                              -- Meeting is contained with in work schedule
                                ( (MS.[BusyST] < AC.[Start]) AND (MS.[BusyET] > AC.[Start])  AND ([MS].[BusyET] < AC.[End]) ) OR   -- Meeting ends within work schedule (partial overlap)
                                ( (MS.[BusyST] > AC.[Start]) AND (MS.[BusyST] < AC.[End])  AND ([MS].[BusyET] > AC.[End]) ) -- Meeting starts within work schedule (partial overlap)
                            ) 
            ) Intervals
),AvailableCoachTimeSegments -- Determine each coach’s availability against each time interval being checked.
AS
(
    SELECT          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TI.CoachID ORDER BY TI.Start, AT.CoachID) AS RankAsc
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TI.CoachID ORDER BY TI.[End] DESC, AT.CoachID DESC) AS RankDesc
                    ,TI.CoachID
                    ,TI.BusyST
                    ,TI.BusyET
                    ,TI.Start
                    ,TI.[End]
                    ,AT.CoachID AS AvailableCoachID
                    ,AT.Start AS AvailableStart
                    ,AT.[End] AS AvailableEnd
                    ,(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (MIN(TI.[Start]) OVER (PARTITION BY TI.CoachID)) <> TI.BusyST THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END
                     ) AS StartIncomplete
                    ,(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (MAX(TI.[End]) OVER (PARTITION BY TI.CoachID)) <> TI.BusyET THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END
                     ) AS EndIncomplete
    FROM            (
                        SELECT   CoachID
                                ,BusyST
                                ,BusyET
                                ,TS AS [Start]
                                ,LEAD(TS, 1, TS) OVER (PARTITION BY CoachID ORDER BY TS) AS [End]
                        FROM    TimeIntervals
                    ) TI    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  ActualAvailability AT ON 

                                (
                                    ( (AT.[Start] <= TI.[Start]) AND (AT.[End] >= TI.[End]) ) OR                                -- Coach availability covers entire time segment 
                                    ( (AT.[Start] > TI.[Start]) AND (AT.[End] < TI.[End]) ) OR                                  -- Coach availability is contained within the time segment 
                                    ( (AT.[Start] < TI.[Start]) AND (AT.[End] > TI.[Start])  AND (AT.[End] < TI.[End]) ) OR     -- Coach availability ends within the time segment (partial overlap)
                                    ( (AT.[Start] > TI.[Start]) AND (AT.[Start] < TI.[End])  AND (AT.[End] > TI.[End]) )        -- Coach availability starts within the time segment (partial overlap)
                                )  
)
-- Final result 
SELECT  CoachID
        ,BusyST
        ,BusyET
        ,Start AS CanCoachST
        ,[End] AS CanCoachET
        ,COUNT(AvailableCoachID) AS NumOfCoaches
         ,ISNULL(STUFF((
                    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ', ' + CAST(AvailableCoach.AvailableCoachID  AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                    FROM AvailableCoachTimeSegments  AvailableCoach
                    WHERE (AvailableCoach.CoachID = Results.CoachID AND AvailableCoach.Start = Results.Start AND  AvailableCoach.[End] = Results.[End]) 
                    ORDER BY AvailableCoach.AvailableCoachID
                    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
                  ,1,2,''), '(No one is available)') AS AvailableCoaches
FROM    AvailableCoachTimeSegments Results
WHERE   [Start] <> [End]
GROUP   BY CoachID, BusyST, BusyET, Start, [End], StartIncomplete, EndIncomplete
UNION ALL -- Add any missing time segments at the start of the busy time or end of the busy time. 
SELECT  CoachID
        ,BusyST
        ,BusyET
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN StartIncomplete = 1 THEN  BusyST
                WHEN EndIncomplete = 1 THEN MAX([End])
                ELSE Start
            END
        ) AS CanCoachST
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN StartIncomplete = 1 THEN  Start
                WHEN EndIncomplete = 1 THEN BusyET
                ELSE [End]
            END
        ) AS CanCoachET
        ,0 AS NumOfCoaches
        ,'(No one is available)' AS AvailableCoaches
FROM    AvailableCoachTimeSegments Results
WHERE   [Start] <> [End] AND ( (StartIncomplete = 1 AND RankAsc = 1) OR (EndIncomplete = 1 AND RankDesc = 1) ) 
GROUP   BY CoachID, BusyST, BusyET, Start, [End], StartIncomplete, EndIncomplete
ORDER BY CoachID, CanCoachST


DROP TABLE #Temp1
DROP TABLE #Temp2
```

Comment: This works too (also like the formatting). Yea, performance is something I really need to look into because this query will run against a HUGE dataset and quite often. Thanks again for this sln @EdmondQuinton.